# Rails: Not able to download rmagick gem on windows machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to install rmagick gem but not able to install it. i have already download imagemagick software(ImageMagick-7.0.2-4-Q16-x64-dll.exe) available for windows 7 64 bit machine from here [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows).

i am trying to install  rmagick gem by using below command

```
gem install rmagick --version=2.15.4 --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=C:/ImageMagick/include
```

But i am getting below error

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-lib=C:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-i
nclude=C:/ImageMagick/include'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-lib=C:/ImageMagick/lib --w
ith-opt-include=C:/ImageMagick/include
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby
extconf.rb:110:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENO
ENT)
        from extconf.rb:110:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:517:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:517:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagi
ck-2.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/ext/RMa
gick/gem_make.out
```

I don't know why rmagick gem is not installing. i have search on the internet about this issue and have followed all the solutions but non of them work for it.

Please help

Comment: Have you found an answer? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: my machine was 64 bit windows but i installed 32 bit windows version of rmagic and it worked for me...

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to solve my issue too. I will put a link to an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) containing steps to follow on how to install `rmagick` if anybody else needs it.